# Resizing the window in web application JSF richfaces

Tags: web-applications, jsf, richfaces, resize

I want to resize the window as and when user adjust the browser. I am catching the resize event and changing the height and width. But it's not working for all. Please give some idea.
I am doing in JSF richfaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not stuck on this fixed/resized layout, you should look for 'fluid' and 'semi-fluid' layouts on the internet. The main idea is to set the sizes in % instead of px or em.

Answer (score 0):

RichFaces has semantic layouts, perhaps that would be useful for you?